# Queuing Theory M/M/n+M Number of Abandons - calculation error

Tags: markov-process, poisson-distribution, queueing-theory

I am trying to work out a queuing theory calculation for a Markov M/M/n+M queue, but cannot get my numbers to match the correct output.

I am trying to calculate the probability that a call abandons.

The formula is given on the last page of this link.

http://iew3.technion.ac.il/serveng/References/Erlang_A_Avi.pdf

The paper provides an answer to the problem (Image of section 4.3) where.

- Number of Agents handling calls = 10
- Average Time to Handle 1 call = 2 minutes
- 300 Calls per 60 minutes
- Average Caller Patience = 2 minutes

This gives a **Probability to Abandon of 12.5%**

I have been using this method to work out the calculation

• λ – arrival rate (calls per unit of time); = 300/ 3600 = 0.083333333 calls per second

• µ – service rate (1/µ is the average duration of service); = 1/ 120 = 0.008333333 calls per second

• n – number of servers/agents; n = 10

• θ – individual abandonment rate (1/θ is the average patience);  = 1/120 = 0.0083333333 calls per second

I then try to work out A(x,y) as given in Equation 3.5

$$A(x,y)=1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty   \frac{(y^j)}{\prod_{k=1}^j(x+k)}$$

Where $$ x = \frac{n \mu} { \theta } $$ = (10  x   0.083333333)/ 0.0083333333 = 10

And $$ y = \lambda / \theta $$ = 0.083333333 / 0.0083333333 = 10

I then work out that A(x,y) = 1.718282

Offered load per agent = $$ \rho = \lambda / n \mu $$ =  0.0083333333 / (10 * 0.008333333 )  = 1

I then try to work out the probability to Abandon

$$P(Ab)=\frac{1} {\rho A(\frac{n \mu} { \theta },\frac{\lambda  } { \theta })} + 1 - \frac{1} {\rho} $$

P(abandon) = 1/( 1 x  4.332748 )   +  1 - (1/1) = 23.08%

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have edited the formula in MathJax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\theta = 0.008333$ gives x = 10 and y = 10.  Please rework A(x,y) and I hope you get the right answer

$$E_{1,n} = \frac{2755}{12842} = .214582$$

$$P(W>0) = \dfrac{.4332748\times0.214582}{1+(.4332748-1)*(.214582)} = .54207$$

$$P\text{{Ab}} =.23\times0.54207 \approx .125$$

Comment: Well spotted.  I gave changed this but still not giving the correct answer 23% not 12.5%

Comment: You will have to calculate P(W>0) there is a formula for that. Once you do that multiply that with 23% you will get 12.5%

Comment: $E_{1,n}$ is the blocking probability and see page 7 for that you need to compute that first and then use it to calculate delay prob. and then multiply that with 23%, I am sure you will get 12.5%

Comment: There was an error in my maths for this.  I computed the Probability of wait as 0.542.  When I multiplied this by 23% I came out with the 12.5% answer.  Which has solved the problem.